# Variance Matrix Hausman Test

Tags: matrices, statistics

[image: [Hausman exercise demonstration. See image]]

Please I have been trying to solve this econometric's problem but I can't figure it out. If anyone has an idea I would really appreciate it.

Comment: No link to an image is visible. This is one of the reasons why images are discouraged.

Comment: @mlc - it is visible now but not much help